# How do I find the max & min values of multiple groups in an Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know about the Pivot-table, but I need summary data in display. That means that I'm also doing other datagathering and Pivot just won't do.

My table looks something like this:

```
Date | Value | Weekday
1.1. | 5903  | Thursday
2.1. | 2981  | Friday
5.1. | 3046  | Monday
6.1. | 5021  | Tuesday
7.1. | 6785  | Wednesday
8.1. | 5074  | Thursday
9.1. | 3631  | Friday
12.1.| 7083  | Monday
13.1.| 3531  | Tuesday
14.1.| 5589  | Wednesday
15.1.| 2068  | Thursday
16.1.| 6485  | Friday
19.1.| 7013  | Monday
20.1.| 3802  | Tuesday
21.1.| 5291  | Wednesday
22.1.| 6142  | Thursday
```

I need to find the MAX and MIN values by the weekday. Note that my table is ordered by dates. I've heard not-so-great stories about VLOOKUP.

So the answers would be:

```
MAX
    12.1.| 7083  | Monday
    6.1. | 5021  | Tuesday
    7.1. | 6785  | Wednesday
    22.1.| 6142  | Thursday
    16.1.| 6485  | Friday

MIN
    5.1. | 3046  | Monday
    13.1.| 3531  | Tuesday
    21.1.| 5291  | Wednesday
    15.1.| 2068  | Thursday
    2.1. | 2981  | Friday
```

What would be the right formula?

Comment: Have you looked into xl2010's [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)? There are many examples of pseudo-MINIF/MAXIF formulas available ([here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-standard-formulas/144a2f30-31ef-408e-86c3-f1443d9ac1fd) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-array-formulas/e81c39b9-458e-46cb-b8cf-12ffbc20794c) for example)

Comment: Shouldn't Friday's MIN be `2.1. | 2981  | Friday` ?

Comment: Jeeped, well spotted. Corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either array or standard pseudo-MINIF/MAXIF formulas to retrieve the value but then you will need a two column lookup to retrieve the value from the Date column.

[image: MINIF and MAXIF with two column lookup]

The formulas for E4:F4,E11:F11 are:

```
'E4
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9999, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+(($B$2:$B$9999<>F4)+($C$2:$C$9999<>G4))*1E+99, , )))
'F4
=MAX(INDEX($B$2:$B$9999*($C$2:$C$9999=G4),,))
'AGGREGATE alternative for F4
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, 1/($C$2:$C$9999=G4)*($B$2:$B$9999),1)
'E11
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9999, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+(($B$2:$B$9999<>F11)+($C$2:$C$9999<>G11))*1E+99, , )))
'F11
=MIN(INDEX($B$2:$B$9999+($C$2:$C$9999<>G11)*1E+99,,))
`F11 where zeroes are discarded
=MIN(INDEX($B$2:$B$9999+(($C$2:$C$9999<>G11)+($B$2:$B$9999=0))*1E+99,,))
'AGGREGATE alternative for F11
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, 1/($C$2:$C$9999=G11)*($B$2:$B$9999),1)
```

Fill each E:F area down as necessary. These formula depend upon the weekday values in columns C & G being text strings; a different approach is required if these are actual dates formatted as *mmmm*

Comment: This works. I took your earlier advice into concideration too and did a bit of research of the aggregate function (it's a bit more difficult for me, since I'm using Office '13 in a different language so I have to format everything again to the language... (Aaand I don't wanna change languages either, I'm not the only one using Excel here.)

Comment: [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) is the 'new-kid-on-the-block' and not widely used as its most common functionality already has almost canonical formula methods in wide use. However, it does provide wider functionality that is much more difficult to achieve using older functions. If you start to use AGGREGATE with the simpler functionality, the more difficult ones will come easier when you need to tackle them. Just remember that the minimum Excel version is 2010 if the workbook will get passed around.

Comment: Thanks for adding in the AGGREGATE's, I'll take those into my lil' study corner and see what's happening with 'em. Stillf figuring out how to ignore zero values in the rows - since I wasn't counting on that being a factor but... meh, I'll try to find an answer. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't think you should need to avoid zeroes from the MAXIF but they could produce undesirable results from the MINIF. See appended formula list above.