# Find Max Value in Column if meets criteria and return corresponding cell value?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with times and tasks like so:

```
   Company: PG Limited

    Task    Time
    A       1
    B       7
    C       9 
    A       10


    Company: BP Limited

    Task    Time
    A       7
    B       3
    C       1 
    A       1
```

I want to find the max value in my Time column where the task is "A" and return the company name.

Can this be done? I would really appreciate help with this.
Here's my max formula:

```
=MAX(IF('Total Data'!D:D="A",'Total Data'!E:E))
```

Here's the adapted formula where i have tried using index match

```
=INDEX('Total Data'!E:E,MATCH(MAX(IF('Total Data'!D:D="Total",'Total Data'!E:E)),'Total Data'!D:D,0))
```

but i just get a #N/A error

Comment: Make sure you are using ***Array formulas*** for both formulas.

Comment: See [How do I find the max & min values of multiple groups in an Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460241/how-do-i-find-the-max-min-values-of-multiple-groups-in-an-excel/31461585#31461585).

Comment: The `Max(IF(...` works perfectly, if you enter it as an array formula, that means, when you enter the formula you would press `Enter`, but now you press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`, just like @Gary'sStudent said.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula: Press Ctr+Shift+Enter after entering formula.

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MAX(IF(A1:B5=MAX(A1:B5),ROW(A1:B5)-ROW(A1)+1)))
```

Screenshot

[image]