# Find max and min value for several numeric column and return dataframe with the corresponding row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset

[image]

For each year column, I would like to find the max and min values and return both the 'max' and 'min' values together with the corresponding 'Geo' value for each.

For instance, for '1950', '1951', and so on, I would like to produce a dataframe like this one:

[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055145/find-max-value-in-column-if-meets-criteria-and-return-corresponding-cell-value) is a similar thread, but the suggested approaches there don't seem to work because my columns have numeric headers, plus my desired result is slightly different.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried looking at [`idxmax` and `idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)?

Comment: Yes, I get `TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype`

Comment: See my explanation below. Basically you are interested in the max and min, as well as the index of each. To do that, you need to 'tidy' the data set (move the years into their own column) and then by setting Geo as your index, you can get those 4 parameters you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but it surely exists a better solution. I supposed your initial dataframe was a pandas dataframe named df.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'row_labels':['Max_value','Max_geo','Min_value','Min_geo']})

for col in df.columns[2:]: #start at column 1950
    col_list = []
    col_list.append(df[col].min())
    col_list.append(df.loc[df[col] == df[col].min(),'Geo'].values[0])
    col_list.append(df[col].max())
    col_list.append(df.loc[df[col] == df[col].max(),'Geo'].values[0])

    dff[col] = col_list

dff.set_index('row_labels', inplace = True, drop = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without having to loop or do any value comparisons to find the max, using `max`, `min`, `idxmax` and `idxmin` as follows (assuming your dataframe is `df`):

```
(df.melt(id_vars='Geo', var_name='year')
   .set_index('geo')
   .groupby('year')
   .agg({'value': ('max', 'idxmax', 'min', 'idxmin')})
   .T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [1915]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Geo':['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Angola'], 'Geo code':[4,8,12,24], '1950':[27.638, 54.191, 42.087, 35.524], '1951':[27.878, 54.399, 42.282, 35.599]})

In [1914]: df
Out[1914]: 
           Geo  Geo code    1950    1951
0  Afghanistan         4  27.638  27.878
1      Albania         8  54.191  54.399
2      Algeria        12  42.087  42.282
3       Angola        24  35.524  35.599

In [1916]: x = df.set_index('Geo').stack().reset_index(level=1, name='value').query('level_1 != "Geo code"')

In [1917]: res = x.groupby('level_1').agg({'value': ('max', 'idxmax', 'min', 'idxmin')}).T

In [1918]: res
Out[1918]: 
level_1              1950         1951
value max          54.191       54.399
      idxmax      Albania      Albania
      min          27.638       27.878
      idxmin  Afghanistan  Afghanistan
```

Comment: This looked promising, but when I try to implement it I get `UndefinedVariableError: name 'level_1' is not defined`

Comment: Did you run my exact commands? It should not happen. `level_1` is the name created by `stack`.