# formula that matches against multiple dates and grabs the most recent

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data table with two columns. The first column has a list of Project IDs, and the second column has a bunch of dates associated with those projects. A project can have multiple dates associated with it.

I would like to create a separate summary table of two columns. The first column will be a list of unique Project IDs (I've been able to do this with an index/match function). I want the second column to search the dates column and identify the most recent date associated with each project.

Is it possible to create this second column of my summary table using standard excel formulas and without using any VBA? After an hour or two, I'm not convinced that this is possible.

I was hoping that, for a given project ID, there might be a way to do the following:

--> identify the row numbers for all rows that contain a given project ID;

--> use this row number information to grab the corresponding cell values from the dates column (presumably by first constructing a list of cell references)

--> display the max date out of those that are returned.

[What my spreadsheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpH8I.png)

Comment: Look into using pivot tables.  This would let you do many functions available to a database, such as rolling up by group.

Comment: There are many variations of a [pseudo-MAXIF function](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-standard-formulas/144a2f30-31ef-408e-86c3-f1443d9ac1fd) available. Lately, I've been using the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF). See[How do I find the max & min values of multiple groups in an Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460241/how-do-i-find-the-max-min-values-of-multiple-groups-in-an-excel/31461585#31461585).

Comment: I was really wanting to do it with hard formulas rather than pivot tables or VBA - or at the least, see if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

The [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can quickly calculate a pseudo-MAXIF function.

In E2 as a standard formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, (B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))/(A$1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,B:B ))=D2), 1)
```

Fill down as necessary.

Like the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff), AGGREGATE benefits from referencing the minimum number of rows necessary. The `MATCH(1E+99,B:B)` truncates each column referenced by the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) at the extents of the daes in column B.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>